# React.js + Express: how to run SQL requests implying several databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, reactjs, express, nodes

I am currently working on the API of a `React.js` project. I have no trouble running SQL requests with databases on MySql servers using Express as long as the SQL request only implies a single database.

**My problem:** I now have to run an SQL request which implies using data from several databases and I do not know how to do it.

**What I currently do in my server.js file to run SQL on a single database:**

```
...
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
...
let sql = "";
...

// *************************
// CLIENT & DB CONFIGURATION
// *************************

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
   extended: true
 }));
 var server = app.listen(3001, "127.0.0.1", function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port 
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
 });
 
 app.use(cors());

 const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'myhost.fr',
  user     : 'someone',
  password : 'aZefdt%',
  database : 'SuiviTruc',
  multipleStatements : true
});


connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('You are now connected with SuiviTruc database...')
});

// **************
// Request sample
// **************

app.get('/SelectAffaire_',(req, res) => {
  let sql=`SELECT * FROM t_Affaire_;`
  connection.query(sql, (error, result)=> {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send(result);
  })
})
```

Thanks for your help!